# Listing a model's attributes, including nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have a model `User`. Each user `has_one` `preference` and `has_many` `companies`.

In "standard" nested attribute form, this relationship might look like

```
{
  "name" => "Foo Bar",
  "email" => "foo.bar@example.co",
  "phone" => "555.555.5555",
  "preference_attributes" => {
    "daily_alerts" => true,
    "time_zone" => "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
  },
  "companies_attributes" => {
    "0" => {
      "name" => "Shinra, Corp",
      "location" => "Midgar"
    },
    "1" => {
      "name" => "Globo Gym",
      "location" => "NYC"
    }
  }
}
```

If I had this hash (`h`), I could easily *update* my user attributes (assuming I have enabled `accepts_nested_hash` for `preference` and `companies`)

```
@user.attributes = h
```

But how do I do the reverse? How do I start with `@user` and generate the nested hash? Simply doing

```
@user.attributes
```

Only gives the `User` model properties, without the nested `preference` or `companies` properties.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be clunky, but it forms a hash of `@user` attributes/values plus the associated relations and their attributes/values.

```
hash = @user.attributes.to_h
associations = User.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name)

associations.each do |association|
  hash[association.to_s] = @user.send(association).map(&:attributes)
end

hash
```

Comment: Thanks! Something like that should work, but was hoping there was a more idiomatic or in-built way to retrieve it.

Comment: I think there's not. Though i would love to be proved wrong